# Adding both a JPanel and JScrollingPane to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I am currently working on a window for a GUI for a database system. I am trying to have both a JScrollPane and a JPanel in the same JFrame. I want basically a part where the user can scroll through the data and then a part on the bottom that doesn't scroll where there are buttons to change the sorting. Currently when I try to open the window only the JPanel is displayed. I know the JScrollPane works by itself because if I comment out the part where the JPanel is added it works like it should.

```
public class ViewWindow
{
   DataContainer data;
   JFrame viewWin;
   DaysUntil days;
   JPanel contentPane;
   JScrollPane scroll;
   EmptyBorder border;
   DateFormat dateformat;
   Integer[] map;
   SortTest sor;
   JButton dayUntil, index, name;

   public ViewWindow(DataContainer da)
   {
       data= da;
       days= new DaysUntil();
       sor= new SortTest(data,days);
       viewWin= createWindow();
       JScrollPane main= createMainPanel();
       JPanel sortPane= createSortPanel();
       viewWin.getContentPane().add(main);
       viewWin.getContentPane().add(sortPane);
       viewWin.pack();
       viewWin.setVisible(false);

  }
```

Here is part of the code for createMainPanel()

```
public JScrollPane createMainPanel()
   {
      DateFormat dateformat =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
      border = new EmptyBorder(10,20,10,20);
      JPanel mainPane= new JPanel();
      mainPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      JPanel titlePane= new JPanel();
      titlePane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(titlePane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

      contentPane= new JPanel();
      contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

      JPanel indexPane= new JPanel();
         indexPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(indexPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
         JLabel indexTitle= new JLabel("index");
         indexTitle.setBorder(border);
         indexPane.add(indexTitle);

       .....
       mainPane.add(titlePane);
  mainPane.add(contentPane);
  JScrollPane mainn= new JScrollPane(mainPane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  return mainn;
 }
```

The JPanel is the following:

```
public JPanel createSortPanel()
   {
      JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();
      sortPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sortPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

      dayUntil= new JButton("Sort by Due Date");
      index= new JButton("Sort by index");
      name= new JButton("Sort by name");
      sortPanel.add(dayUntil);
      sortPanel.add(index);
      sortPanel.add(name);
      return sortPanel;
   }
```

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default layout of a JFame is a BorderLayout which supports this requirement:

The basic logic is:

```
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER)
frame.add(anotherPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples to better help you understand how a `BorderLayout` works.

Comment: Would it work if I switched the default layout to one like a box layout?

Comment: @J.Shupperd,  You can do whatever you want but for the requirement you describe I stongly suggest there is no need to change the layout of the content pane of the frame layout from the default BorderLayout. The BorderLayout will better handle resizing of the frame than the BoxLayout would. You can use different layout managers on your child panels. Read the tutorial, download the examples and play with them you so you understand how each layout works.

Comment: @J.Shupperd to expand on camickr's answer a bit: in a BorderLayout, the center 'pane' stretches as the JFrame stretches, in both directions. The 'page_end' 'pane' stretches horizontally only. This is normally what is wanted, and matches what you describe. Playing with the different layout managers is a good idea.